# Removing non-alphanumeric symbols in dataframe

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

How do I remove non-alphabet from the values in the dataframe? I only managed to convert all to lower case

```
def doubleAwardList(self):
        dfwinList = pd.DataFrame()
        dfloseList = pd.DataFrame()
        dfwonandLost = pd.DataFrame()
        #self.dfWIN... and self.dfLOSE... is just the function used to call the files chosen by user
        groupby_name= self.dfWIN.groupby("name")
        groupby_nameList= self.dfLOSE.groupby("name _List")

        list4 = []
        list5 = []

        notAwarded = "na"

        for x, group in groupby_name:
            if x != notAwarded:
                list4.append(str.lower(str(x)))
        dfwinList= pd.DataFrame(list4)

        for x, group in groupby_nameList:
            list5.append(str.lower(str(x)))
        dfloseList = pd.DataFrame(list5)
```

data sample: Basically I mainly need to remove the full stops and hyphens as I will require to compare it to another file but the naming isn't very consistent so i had to remove the non-alphanumeric for much more accurate result

```
creative-3
smart tech pte. ltd.
nutritive asia
asia's first
```

desired result:

```
creative 3
smart tech pte ltd
nutritive asia
asia s first
```

Comment: Can you add some data sample?

Comment: Is that a `Series` or `DataFrame`?

Comment: @U9-Forward DataFrame

Comment: @nevertoolateyet See my answer

Comment: @nevertoolateyet So that means one to assign to whole dataframe, right?

Comment: @U9-Forward sorry what do you mean by one to assign to whole dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) only and add whitespace to pattern:

```
df = df.replace('[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]', '', regex=True)
```

If one column - `Series`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': ['creative-3', 'smart tech pte. ltd.', 
                           'nutritive asia', "asia's first"],
                   'col2':range(4)})
print (df)
                    col  col2
0            creative-3     0
1  smart tech pte. ltd.     1
2        nutritive asia     2
3          asia's first     3

df['col'] = df['col'].replace('[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]', '', regex=True)
print (df)

                  col  col2
0           creative3     0
1  smart tech pte ltd     1
2      nutritive asia     2
3         asias first     3
```

EDIT:

If multiple columns is possible select only object, obviously string columns and if necessary cast to strings:

```
cols = df.select_dtypes('object').columns
print (cols)
Index(['col'], dtype='object')

df[cols] = df[cols].astype(str).replace('[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]', '', regex=True)
print (df)
                  col  col2
0           creative3     0
1  smart tech pte ltd     1
2      nutritive asia     2
3         asias first     3
```

Comment: i'm facing the current error though.
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

Comment: @nevertoolateyet - What solution is used?

Comment: If one of last 2 use `df['col'] = df['col'].astype(str).replace('[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]', '', regex=True)`

Comment: TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

Sorry additional question, i put it after the append portion of the code is right right?
list4['name']=list4['name'].str.replace('[^a-zA-Z0-9]', '')
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

Comment: @nevertoolateyet - No problem. Can you post all your code? Because instead your all code use only  this line, no append is necessary.

Comment: i'll update it because this is a group project we needed it to print into a GUI

Comment: @nevertoolateyet - Thank you. So need repalce all columns or only one?

Comment: @nevertoolateyet - Added samples to answer.

Comment: @jazrael 1 column each file! So i guess you can guide me on one will do!

Comment: @nevertoolateyet - Yes, then need only `df['col'] = df['col'].replace('[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]', '', regex=True)` - `col` is colum name, if `name` then use `self.dfWIN['name'] = self.dfWIN['name'].replace('[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]', '', regex=True)`

Answer (score 0):

Why not just the below, (i did make into lower btw):

```
df=df.replace('[^a-zA-Z0-9]', '',regex=True).str.lower()
```

Then now:

```
print(df)
```

Will get the desired data-frame

#### Update:

try:

```
df=df.apply(lambda x: x.str.replace('[^a-zA-Z0-9]', '').lower(),axis=0)
```

If only one column do:

```
df['your col']=df['your col'].str.replace('[^a-zA-Z0-9]', '').str.lower()
```

Comment: list4['name']=list4['name'].str.replace('[^a-zA-Z0-9]', '').str.lower()

Am i right?
The follow eror occured, TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str


Sorry i've just learned python programming for 2 weeks only.

Comment: @nevertoolateyet Then try: `list4['name']=list4['name'].astype(str).str.replace('[^a-zA-Z0-9]', '').str.lower()`